# How to predict different labels for different customers

Tags: machine-learning

Let's say I'm a picture hosting company and I want to do face recognition in the pictures of all my customers. Each of my customer already has a set of labeled pictures and I use a supervised algorithm to label the new ones.

The question is : should I use a different model for each customer to label their pictures ?

On one hand, if I use a single model for all my customers I fear that I might label pictures of customer A with labels from customer B. On the other hand, if I use a model for each customer I will have thousands of models to manage (deploy, update, monitor..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to develop or learn a hierarchical structure among all your labels.  Suppose it looks like below (each node in the tree is a label):

```
A->B1->C1
|->B2->C2
|
|->B3->C3->D3->E3
```

There are parent-child relations between labels. For example, `C1` is `B1`'s child (`C1` is more specific, `B1->C1` could be Sports->Tennis)

For the model itself, it could see all the labels at training time across all customers. 
At prediction time, you first run the same model and output possibilities of each label (suppose your model is something like N-way logistic). For example,

```
B1: 0.1
B2: 0.15
B3: 0.05
C1: 0.4
C2: 0.9
C3: 0.01
D3: 0.001
E4: 0
```

Now if this is a task for customer A (whose only active labels are `B2` and `C3`), you can rollup your labels to match the active labels and remove other branches:

```
B2: 0.9 (we use a Max(B2, C2) here)
C3: 0.011
```

So you should report B2 here given that you don't want to label pictures of customer A with labels from customer B. However once you have a lot of customers, applying some popular labels to customer A should not be a problem, right?